# Avoid Line Repeat in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP code that reads data from text files and it searches for a certain word and echos it, for example, I search for

> [Error]

Is it possible to only echo the word I search for only 1 time (aka if the word "Error" is found twice, only echo it once!)

```
    $file = 'filesexample/'.$fileNameNew;
    $searchfor = 'error';

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
       echo "Errors Found:\n";
       echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
    }
```

Can I do this?

Comment: `echo $searchfor;` instead?

Comment: Use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove the duplicates from an array.

Comment: @jeroen it will echo 'error'; not the data in the text file

Comment: @axiac I tried it as someone posted this in the answers but not working too.

Comment: @MarwanKhaled Can you give me a sample of the txt file? post it in your question not in a comment

Comment: @MehdiBounya
it is
[error]1
[error]2
[error]2
[error]1

so i want the error 2 once and the error 1 once too.

Comment: @MarwanKhaled No please, give me an example of a text file you are working with, hide any sensitive data and make it short

Comment: Thanks for your time, @user2342558 fixed this anyways. Thanks bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique) PHP's function which remove duplicate values from an array:

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
{
    $matches[0] = array_unique($matches[0]);

    echo "Errors Found:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: sorry, try now (with `$matches[0]`)

Comment: please, I have in $searchfor = 'error';
Each time i need to search for another word i repeat the function

can't i set the $searchfor value to many values like: 'error1' and 'error2' and 'error3' but don't stop the code if one (error1) of the values didn't exist?

Comment: sure :) but post a new question for that, I'll answer you

Comment: It says I need 90 minutes to post again, I will post the link here as soon as i am allowed to post

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348258/can-i-set-many-values-for-the-same-variable