# Can I set many values for the same variable?

Tags: php

I have a PHP variable that its value = keywords the code searches for

```
$searchfor = 'error1';
```

Each time I need to add a new keyword to searchfor, i repeat the function.
Can't I for example set

```
$searchfor = 'error1' and 'error2' and 'error3';
```

but don't stop the code if one of them didn't exist.

Comment: use an array...

Comment: You could use an array `$searchfor = ['error1', 'error2', 'error3'];`

Comment: Search for where?  How?

Comment: How do you want to use $searchfor after?

Comment: Hi, please explain more details in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

computer programming more verbose than human language.  this is so that there is no ambiguity.

No, you must do this:

```
if( $searchfor == 'value1' || $searchfor == 'value2' || $searchfor == 'value3' )
{
    // do something
}
```

You must repeat the variable name.

Or you could use an array

```
$searchfor = 'value1';
$goodValues = array( 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' );
if( in_array( $searchfor, $goodValues ) )
{
    echo 'hi mom';
}
```

Output:

```
hi mom
```

it's up to you to decide which style best suits your needs.

Comment: I prefer the 2nd one, but how will I use in_array($searchfor) if I only defined $goodValues?

Can you please give me an example using $searchfor because i can't get it